# Remove row from database if image not on server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with a table in the following format:

ID: 1
Date: 2010-12-19
Image: 5d61240f-7aca-d34b-19-12-10-15-36.jpg
Caption: Merry Xmas

I want to create a php script which checks through each row in this table and checks that the image is present in a gallery folder on my server. If the image is not in the gallery folder then I want to delete this row from my database. Some pointers on how to go about doing this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, read all lines from the database and check if the picture exists, if not, delete the row...what was your question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<?php

    define ("GALLERY_ROOT", "/path/to/gallery/" );

    $mysqli = new MySQLi ($host, $username, $password, $db);

    $result = $mysqli -> query ("
        SELECT
            id,
            image
        FROM
            table
    ");

    if ( $result ){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ( !is_file (GALLERY_ROOT . $row['image'] ) ){
                $mysqli -> query ("
                    DELETE FROM
                        table
                    WHERE
                        id = '" . $row['id'] . "'
                    LIMIT 1
                ");

                print "Deleted " . $row['id'] . "<br />";
            }
        }

        $result -> free();
    }

    $mysqli -> close();

    print "Congratz!! All invalid rows has been deleted!";
?>
```

That was a quick one, i didn't try running it actually.

Also if you have a lot of rows, then you might want to rethink about selecting all the rows at once. But again get back to me on how it works

Answer (score 0):

Ok... use `glob()` or the `DirectoryIterator`, `file_exists()`, the `mysql_` or `mysqli_` functions, and `'DELETE FROM images WHERE id = ?'`. :)

Hope this helps! If you supply some more information, I could give you more detailed advice. What have you tried so far?

EDIT: wait, I misread. You don't need the directory functions, as you already have the filename. `dirname(__FILE__)` might be useful.