# Add rows to database based on images in folder

Tags: php, mysql

This follows on from a question I had earlier about cleaning up my database which you can see here: [Remove row from database if image not on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497763/remove-row-from-database-if-image-not-on-server)

I have a mysql database with a table in the following format:

ID: 1
Date: 2010-12-19
Image: 5d61240f-7aca-d34b-19-12-10-15-36.jpg
Caption: Merry Xmas

I now want to create a php script which checks through my /gallery/ folder on my server and for every image in the gallery folder that isn't already listed in my database I want to create a new row with it's filename in the image column. The ID is sequential, the date needs to be the last modified date of the file using filetime() and needs to be in the YYYY-MM-DD format. The caption column can be blank for these files we're adding. Any help with a script to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you comed up with yourself? Are you having problems with some specific part of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// list of allowed image extensions
$image_exts=array('png','jpg','ico','gif','bmp'); // ...

// function to store image file to db
function db_add_image($image){
    $name=mysql_real_escape_string(basename($image));
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`ID`,`Date`,`Image`,`Caption`)
        VALUES (NULL,'".date('Y-m-d',filemtime($image))."','".$name."','')
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `ID` FROM `table` WHERE `Image`='".$name."')");
}

// loop in your folder (glob returns an array of files matching a wildcard)
foreach(glob('gallery/*.*') as $file)
    // if the file is an image...
    if(in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),$image_exts))
        // add image to database
        db_add_image($file);
```

Secure, clean, commented and ready for shipping. That's $20 in all, please pay at the counter. :D

**Edit:** Thanks to the two guys below, +1 to both.

Comment: Am I missing something, does the code check if the image is already listed in database? I think that is one of the requirement - please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Rutesh: you're correct. Just need to fix the `db_Add_image` function with: `$imgName = mysql_real_escape_string(basename($image)); mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (ID,Date,Image,Caption) VALUES (NULL,'".date('Y-m-d',filemtime($image))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(basename($image))."','') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Image='".$imgName."')");`

Comment: Thank you so much! This works really well. Indeed with @Rutesh's addition it only added the files which weren't already in the DB.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!empty($_FILES["photo_name"]["name"]) && file_exists($_FILES["photo_name"]["tmp_name"]))
// Image is empty
// photo_name is image box name
{
    if (strtolower($_FILES["photo_name".$i]["type"])!="image/jpg" && strtolower($_FILES["photo_name".$i]["type"])!="image/pjpeg" && strtolower($_FILES["photo_name".$i]["type"])!="image/jpeg")  //Image is not jpg or gif 
    {
        $_MSG[] = " The Image Must be JPG/JPEG.";
        $error = 1;     
    }
}

if (empty($error)) 
{
    if (!empty($_FILES["photo_name"]["name"]) && file_exists($_FILES["photo_name"]["tmp_name"])) // Image is exist
    {   
        if(!$_POST["hidImage"]) 
        {
            $original = rand(1,9).date("Hismdy").".jpg"; //Make file name as timestampe
            $_POST["hidImage"]=$original;   
        }
        else
            $original = $_POST["hidImage"]; 

        chmod($_DIR['inc']['regi_images'],0777); 

        //regi_images is folder name
        $image = $_FILES["photo_name"]["tmp_name"];         
        $arr = getimagesize($image);

        if($arr[0]>400) 
        {
            setsize("400x400");
            // Size Width x Height
            resize($newwidth,$newheight,$_DIR['inc']['regi_images'].$original);
        } else 
            copy($image,$_DIR['inc']['regi_images'].$original);

        chmod($_DIR['inc']['regi_images'],0755);
    } else
        $original = $_POST["hidImage"];
}
```